# How to display Json data on UI in angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular6

I am trying to display a json object in the UI. I am able to show the json object but when I try to display the object inside the object, I am getting errors. Please help me on this.

Comment: What are the errors? Please add them to the question.

Comment: Where is your template accessing power?

Comment: Please describe how you are trying to "print the power value". Also, describe the errors you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

Your description isn't terribly clear, but to address the title, you can display a JSON representation of JavaScript Objects in the UI with Angular by using a `<pre>` element and the built-in JSON pipe like this:

```
<pre>{{details | json}}</pre>
```

Comment: what details you need?i will share

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
{{details.nwedev.alldata.states.values.power}}
```

you probably have been accessing incorrectly to the value, try to log the json to make sure that field exist.

Comment: thanks for your response.i am also try this solution before but getting lot of errors like each object is what i am used in undefined it showing in console.